# How to get the azure devops workitems I'm following, using REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I tried to use wiql, but still I can't contruct a query to return the workitemids which are followed by me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show list of work items I am following in VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934498/show-list-of-work-items-i-am-following-in-vsts)

Comment: The Microsoft REST API Docs for Azure DevOps can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/work%20item%20search%20results/fetch%20work%20item%20search%20results?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and should provide enough information to get what you require. Another good tip is to look at the Network tab when debugging Chrome to find what Requests the Azure DevOps UI is using.

Comment: Hi @Arun Joshla. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions. If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter used to get the followed work item is `System.id In @Follows`.

You could check this filter by clicking the `Open in Queries` option.

[image]

Since you are using the wiql to get the workitem , you could using the following [Rest API - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

The Request Body sample:

```
{
  "query": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType],  [System.State],[System.AreaPath],[System.Tags],[System.CommentCount],[System.ChangedDate] FROM workitems WHERE[System.Id] IN(@follows) AND [System.TeamProject] = 'Project Name' AND [System.State] <> '' ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC"
}
```

By the way, you could use this [Wiql Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor) extension to convert query into wiql syntax. It will be more convenient.

**Update:**

My activity:

Request Body:

```
{
  "query": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title],[System.AssignedTo], [System.State],[System.AreaPath],[System.Tags], [System.CommentCount]FROM workitems WHERE [System.Id] IN (@myRecentActivity)  AND [System.TeamProject] = 'Project name'  ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC"
}
```

Mentioned:

Request Body:

```
{
  "query": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title],[System.AssignedTo], [System.State],[System.AreaPath],[System.Tags], [System.CommentCount]FROM workitems WHERE [System.Id] IN (@recentMentions)  AND [System.TeamProject] = 'Projectname'  ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC"
}
```

**Update2:**

The limit of work item number is 20000.

[image]

In this case, you can add filter to group query.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!
Can u pls tell a similar query for 'Mentioned' and 'My activity' filters.

Comment: Hi @ArunJoshla. Please check the update. I have added the 'Mentioned' and 'My activity' filters.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
What is the limit on the number of work items retrieved? if there is a limit.

Comment: Hi @ArunJoshla. The limit of the result is 20000.

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin!
Just curious to know, what is the purpose of  " [System.State] <> '' " in Following filter?

Comment: Please check this doc about query operators:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=azure-devops#query-operators  `[System.State] <> '' " ` this means any state.

Comment: If I don't add this condition in the WHERE part. It will still give the same result right?

Comment: Thanks a bunch Kevin! You made my day!